# C/CPP - Converting floating point arithmetic to integer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, floating-point, integer

I have the following c++ functions (implementing [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)), seen in the book

> Computer Graphics From Pixels to Programmable Graphics Hardware By
> Alexey Boreskov, Evgeniy Shikin

One of the function uses floats, and due to their inefficiency the book has presented another function which uses integer arithmetic only.

I'm having trouble understading why are the two equivalent, and why are we using left shift `<<` here, doesn't `a<<1` simply multiply `a` by 2?

**Note**: We assume the points `A:(xa,ya)` and `B:(xb,yb)` have integer values.

---

### Float Version

```
void drawLine(int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb, int color) {
    float k = (float)(yb-ya)/(float)(xb-xa);
    float d = 2*k - 1
    int y = ya;

    putPixel(xa, ya, color); // paint the pixel (xa,ya) in color "color"

    for (int x = xa+1; x<=xb; x++) {
        if (d > 0) {
            d += 2*k + 2;
            y++;
        } else {
            d += 2*k;
        }
        putPixel(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

### Integer Version

```
void drawLine(int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb, int color) {
    int dx = xb - xa;
    int dy = yb -ya;
    int d = (dy<<1) - dx;
    int d1 = dy <<1;
    int d2 = (dy - dx) << 1;
    int y = ya;

    putPixel(xa, ya, color); // paint the pixel (xa,ya) in color "color"

    for (int x = xa+1; x<=xb; x++) {
        if (d > 0) {
            d += d2;
            y++;
        } else {
            d += d1;
        }
        putPixel(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Old compilers might emit *better* (for suitable values of *better*) code with `value << 1` than with `value * 2`. Current compilers will emit the same code.

Comment: @pmg It is still unclear to me why the functions are equivalent, how can they both give the same output if we never use division (for example I think the slope `k` must be represented using division, but in the 2nd function there is not `k` and there is no division)

Comment: Ah ... your question is deeper than I thought, sorry.

Comment: All of the ds are dx times larger in the int version.  As they are only compared with zero...  I do see what looks like a typo, a + and - swapped?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont no typos on my end, I can't say if the book writer had a typo

Comment: Bresenham's algorithm is very efficient and will give consistent results regardless of the starting coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The floating-point code does four things with `d`:

1. Initialize `d` to 2*dy*/*dx*−1, where *dy* and *dx* are `yb`−`ya` and `xb`−`xa`, respectively.
2. Evaluate whether `d` is greater than 0.
3. Add 2*dy*/*dx*+2 to `d`.
4. Add 2*dy*/*dx* to `d`.

In floating-point, the division by *dx* may produce a non-integer. To avoid this, we transform the operations by multiplying everything by *dx*, yielding:

1. Initialize `d` to 2*dy*−*dx*.
2. Evaluate whether `d` is greater than 0*dx* (equal to 0).
3. Add 2*dy*+2*dx* to `d`.
4. Add 2*dy* to `d`.

We can readily see that these four equivalent operations are implemented in the integer code except for 3. The integer code appears to add 2*dy*−2*dx* to `d`. The integer code matches code shown in [the Wikipedia page for Bresenham’s line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). I suspect the `+` in the floating-point version is an error in the book.

Comment: It appears to be a typo in the book, Thank you for the explanation